# Angular4 Firebase FirebaseListObservable control index to display on html

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I want to create a leaderboard in my application.So I need to read the names and totalscores  info from the Firebase Database and display them on browser.
My goal is to to display something like this on browser but replace the Unknown with database usernames and topscores of course.

> Leaderboard
>
> First:Unknown,Topscore:Unknown
>
> Second:Unknown,Topscore:Unknown
>
> Third:Unknown,Topscore:Unknown
>
> Fourth:Unknown,Topscore:Unknown
>
> Fifth:Unknown,Topscore:Unknown

My firebase database is:

```
"users" : {
    "Test1" : {
      "totalscore" : 50,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test2" : {
      "totalscore" : 30,
      "username" : "test2"
    },
    "Test3" : {
      "totalscore" : 20,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test4" : {
      "totalscore" : 10,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test5" : {
      "totalscore" : 50,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test6" : {
      "totalscore" : 30,
      "username" : "test2"
    },
    "Test7" : {
      "totalscore" : 20,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test8" : {
      "totalscore" : 10,
      "username" : "test1"
    }
  }
```

With the following code I can get the inverted info from what I want.

```
topusers: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {


        this.topusers = db.list('users', {
        query: {
         orderByChild: "totalscore",
         limitToLast: 10,
        }
        });
   }
```

And last using *ngFor I can display the 5 topscores from the fifth to the first.

```
<ul *ngFor="let topuser of topusers | async">
  <li class = "white" > 
      {{ topuser.username | json }}:
      {{ topuser.totalscore | json }}          
  </li>
</ul>
```

My question is that is there any way to control the *ngFor so instead to start from the first index of the list to start from the last and end on the first??
Or is there anyway I can control the index of the FirebaseListObservable that I want to display on the browser??

Comment: You can try adding a map function to the observable to reverse the order of the return. .map(res => res.reverse())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily want to manipulate the order of the ngFor but instead manipulate the data being passed into the ngFor. You can reverse the order of the data returned from the firebase observable with the .map method

```
topusers: Observable<any>; // use Observable<> instead of FirebaseListObservable<> since .map is an rxjs method that returns the type Observable

constructor(){
    this.topusers = db.list('users', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: "totalscore",
            limitToLast: 10,
        }
    })
    .map(res => res.reverse());
}
```

So now the array being passed to the ngFor is reversed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but when i use `.map(res => res.reverse());` on the function I get error into this.users saying ** [ts]
Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'.
  Property '$ref' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.  **                              I import `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';` to use map right??

Comment: @Zekelonas you'll want to import the map function. import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Comment: I am still geting the same error on this.users ` Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'.
  Property '$ref' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.`

Comment: looks like this is a common issue https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/type-observable-any-is-not-assignable-to-type-firebaselistobservable-any/75683
so you could turn topusers: FirebaseListObservable<any>; into topusers: Observable<any>;

Comment: you also may be able to specify that the map function is to return a FirebaseListObservable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094860/angularfire2-type-observableany-is-not-assignable-to-type-firebaselistob

Comment: I dont know how this happens but it dont work always.. sometimes it starts from highest to lowest but sometimes the opposite.. should I use a promise or something?? what exactly res on `.map(res => res.reverse());` means??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151169/discussion-between-llai-and-zekelonas).